# TeamCity Build agent. Как обновить версию PowerShell, используем Build agent'ом?

Tags: powershell, непрерывная-интеграция, teamcity

Для подстановки номера билда установил [semver-buildnumber](https://github.com/JetBrains/meta-runner-power-pack/tree/master/semver-buildnumber)

Получаю сообщение:

> Incompatible agents. Unmet requirements: powershell_x86 matches
>   3.0(.\d+)?(.\d+)?|4.0(.\d+)?(.\d+)?|5.0(.\d+)?(.\d+)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Судя по сообщению об ошибке, требуется версия PowerShell с 3-й по 5-ю, а в переменных конфигураций (Agent Parameters -> Configuration Parameters) у меня указана 2-я версия
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как установить на данный Build Agent версию PowerShell 3, 4 или 5-й версии?
В переменной 'powershell_x86_Path' указан путь к powershell. Проверил его, он 5-й версии, а не 2-й, что собственно странно

Может нужно просто цифру 2 на 5 сменить в конфигурации 'powershell_x86'? Пытался найти в папке установленного Build Agent'а файл конфигурации, где указана настройка 'powershell_x86', но безуспешно.

Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что ты не видишь свою настройку значит, что она по умолчанию(видимо в реестре где-то). В папке агента "conf" есть файл "buildAgent.properties" с настройками агента. Просто добавь в файл строчку:

```
powershell_x64=5.0
```

Затем перезапусти агента. Достаточно disable и следом enable в управлении агентами, необходимости перезагружать саму машину вроде нет.